# MVC5 uploading pictures along side with data

Tags: javascript, ajax, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So, I've ran into a problem with using

```
<input type="file" multiple id="fileUpload" name="photos[]" accept="image/*" />
```

It is not encapsulated inside  tags.

Every time I select an image, it does not get updated, only on the refresh, it is.
For some reason I noticed every time I select an image, it tries to do a POST method, and it just stays as "No Files Selected".

This is my server-side method for capturing images, do note, this only works if I select files, then refresh the page, and click on a button "Save".

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveTickets(string gridData)
{
   if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
   {
   //logic    
   }
}
```

My methods are working, but I have no idea with is input `type="file"` requiring me to refresh a page for it to load the pictures?

Additional code since asked, my ajax method for sending data to server.

```
    function saveTickets() {
    var gridData = $("#TicketsGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var files = $("#fileUpload").prop("files");

    formData.append('gridData', JSON.stringify(gridData));

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];

        // Check the file type.
        if (!file.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        // Add the file to the request.
        formData.append('photos[]', file, file.name);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("SaveTickets", "Ticket"))",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "formData",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (json) {
            if (json.Flag == "emptylist") { alert("No tickets to add."); }
            else if (json.Flag == "insertion_success") { alert(json.TicketCount + " tickets inserted successfuly!"); cleanTicketsGrid(); lockEventsGrid(false); }
            else if (json.Flag == "insertion_failure") { alert(json.TicketCount + " tickets failed to insert!");}
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this code that you all have? why `ajax` and javascript?

Comment: I have a specific task that is not "doable" with plain form. Im relying on another framework, and the task I got is kind of a specific one. I need to be able to fill a gird, and attach photos underneath, and then post it to server.

Comment: Have a look at:[here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/uploading-multiple-files-in-asp-net-mvc/) but its without `ajax` quite clean

Comment: It would be okay if I didn't have additional data that is tied to images.

Comment: Okay, as I dont know the requirement, but I would suggest to --> *use model instead!*

Comment: Still, I'm not able to change whole architecture now, I'm just trying to prevent input type="file" from autosubmiting everytime I add a file, and for it to display the files it contains.

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45944123/prevent-file-input-from-changing-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: It actually did help... Thanks.

Comment: Seriously? Just made a guess!